# Columns don't fit to header - datatables with Scroller plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, scroller

I'm using Datatables with Scroller plugin and server-side loading. When data are loaded, header columns are resized and often (not always) don't fit to inside columns.

Picture of a situation (https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3zMz.png):

[image]

Relevant datatables setting code:

```
"sScrollY" : window.innerHeight - 270,
            "bServerSide" : true,
            "sDom" : "frtiS",
            "bProcessing" : true,
            "bDeferRender" : true,
            "bAutoWidth" : true,
            "oScroller" : {
                "rowHeight" : 33,
                "autoHeight" : false,
                "serverWait" : 100
            },
```

Is there any way how force header columns to always fit the content (and vice versa)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(window).load( function () {
   $('#myTable').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing( false );
} );
```